# Cannot find symbol variable for a View (Android Studio)

Tags: android, view, compiler-errors

My method *newNum* with parameter *resetB* is being called on a button onClick but I would also like it to run in onCreate. For some reason when I try to call `newNum(resetB);` in onCreate it gives me the error: **Cannot find symbol variable resetB**. I don't understand why this is. Any help would be appreciated!

```
  public void newNum(View resetB){
    TextView numOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numOne);
    TextView numTwo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numTwo);
    TextView ans = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans);
    Button reset = (Button) resetB;

    Random rand = new Random();
    int  ranOne = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
    int  ranTwo = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
    int  ansNum = (ranOne/2) + ranTwo;

    numOne.setText("" + ranOne);
    numTwo.setText("" + ranTwo);
    ans.setText("" + ansNum);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    newNum(resetB);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable resetB is not defined in the scope `onCreate`. Try:

```
View reset = findViewById(R.id.<>); // Put the id of the button with the onClick attribute
newNum( reset );
```